# Page does not render completely and keeps on flickering through appium but renders correctly when done manually

Tags: android, appium

I have a test case scenario to add medicine to a cart as below:

1. send medicine name in textbox
2. from the search results select the medicine by clicking ADD button
3. verify add medicine

**Issue**: When I click on the add button in step 2, the medicine gets added, but the page starts to flicker i.e. page keeps on rendering or refreshing (I don't know what to call in exactly), and so I am not able to perform the next steps.

One more concern is that the same scenario works perfectly when executed manually. The issue occurs only for execution done via appium. If I stop the appium server at the point where issue occurs, the flickering stops.
So seems to me like appium is messing something up.

My Android app is React Native app.

At the point of failure I can see below failure in adb logs:

> Conv2QueryExtension: Conv2Query not enabled due to current app [com.medlife.customer] not in whitelist

ADB logs:

```
09-19 15:20:05.274  2132  2132 I LatinIme: onActivate() : EditorInfo = Package = com.medlife.customer : Type = Text : Learning = Disable : Suggestion = Hide : AutoCorrection = Disable : Microphone = Show : Incognito = Disable
09-19 15:20:05.690  2132  2132 W Conv2QueryExtension: Conv2Query not enabled due to current app [com.medlife.customer] not in whitelist
09-19 15:20:10.719  2132  2132 I LatinIme: onActivate() : EditorInfo = Package = com.medlife.customer : Type = Text : Learning = Disable : Suggestion = Hide : AutoCorrection = Disable : Microphone = Show : Incognito = Disable
09-19 15:20:10.770 15240 15240 I chatty  : uid=10105(com.medlife.customer) expire 5 lines
09-19 15:20:10.784  2132  2132 W Conv2QueryExtension: Conv2Query not enabled due to current app [com.medlife.customer] not in whitelist
09-19 15:20:10.809  2132  2132 I LatinIme: onActivate() : EditorInfo = Package = com.medlife.customer : Type = Text : Learning = Disable : Suggestion = Hide : AutoCorrection = Disable : Microphone = Show : Incognito = Disable
09-19 15:20:10.916  2132  2132 W Conv2QueryExtension: Conv2Query not enabled due to current app [com.medlife.customer] not in whitelist
```

ADB logs while executing on real device:

```
09-26 16:11:30.314   775   775 D SurfaceFlinger: duplicate layer name: changing com.medlife.customer/com.medlife.customer.MainActivity to com.medlife.customer/com.medlife.customer.MainActivity#1
09-26 16:11:30.524 30011 30084 I chatty  : uid=10273(com.medlife.customer) expire 45 lines
09-26 16:11:30.611   775  1301 W SurfaceFlinger: Attempting to set client state on removed layer: Splash Screen com.medlife.customer#0
09-26 16:11:30.611   775  1301 W SurfaceFlinger: Attempting to destroy on removed layer: Splash Screen com.medlife.customer#0
09-26 16:11:32.669 30011 30132 I chatty  : uid=10273(com.medlife.customer) expire 5 lines
09-26 16:11:32.695 30011 30134 I chatty  : uid=10273(com.medlife.customer) expire 4 lines
09-26 16:11:32.980   775  1301 W SurfaceFlinger: Attempting to set client state on removed layer: com.medlife.customer/com.medlife.customer.MainActivity#1
09-26 16:11:32.980   775  1301 W SurfaceFlinger: Attempting to destroy on removed layer: com.medlife.customer/com.medlife.customer.MainActivity#1
09-26 16:11:33.313 30011 30022 I chatty  : uid=10273(com.medlife.customer) expire 3 lines
09-26 16:11:33.317 30011 30020 I chatty  : uid=10273(com.medlife.customer) expire 36 lines
09-26 16:11:43.478 30011 30011 I chatty  : uid=10273(com.medlife.customer) expire 12 lines
09-26 16:11:46.282  1451  1644 D ActivityManager: handleProcessStartedLocked mDoneFinishBooting && app.pid != 0 ---> notifyProcessStart, app.processName = android:ui, app.info = ApplicationInfo{58c1294 android}, app.hostingType = activity, getHostingName() = ComponentInfo{android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity}, getIntentFlag() = 0, getIsPackageRunning() = false, app = ProcessRecord{ae3a8d2 30232:android:ui/1000}, getExtraData() = Bundle[{ACTIVITY_TASK_AFFINITY=android, ACTIVITY_INTENT=Intent { act=android.intent.action.CHOOSER flg=0x800000 cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity (has extras) }, CALLER_PACKAGE=com.medlife.customer, ACTIVITY_INFO=ActivityInfo{382be16 com.android.internal.app.ChooserActivity}}]
09-26 16:11:47.830  1451  1714 D AR_ADV_APPS_USAGE_COL: com.medlife.customer -> resizable apps -> USAGE 17406
09-26 16:11:51.603 30011 30084 I chatty  : uid=10273(com.medlife.customer) expire 624 lines
09-26 16:11:54.508 30011 30011 I chatty  : uid=10273(com.medlife.customer) expire 1 line
09-26 16:11:54.619  2492  2492 I AndroidIME: PasswordIme.onActivate() : EditorInfo = Package = com.medlife.customer : Type = Text : Learning = Disable : Suggestion = Show : AutoCorrection = Disable : Microphone = Show : NoPersonalizedLearning = Disable
09-26 16:11:54.798  2492  2492 I ConversationToQueryExtension: Conv2Query not enabled due to current app [com.medlife.customer] not in whitelist
09-26 16:11:55.057  2492  2492 I AndroidIME: LatinIme.onActivate() : EditorInfo = Package = com.medlife.customer : Type = Text : Learning = Disable : Suggestion = Hide : AutoCorrection = Disable : Microphone = Show : NoPersonalizedLearning = Disable
09-26 16:11:55.191  2492  2492 I ConversationToQueryExtension: Conv2Query not enabled due to current app [com.medlife.customer] not in whitelist
09-26 16:11:59.524 30011 30020 I chatty  : uid=10273(com.medlife.customer) expire 3 lines
09-26 16:12:09.589 30011 30084 I chatty  : uid=10273(com.medlife.customer) expire 541 lines
09-26 16:12:23.113 30011 30084 I chatty  : uid=10273(com.medlife.customer) expire 21 lines
09-26 16:12:30.807  1451  2766 I ActivityManager: Force stopping com.medlife.customer appid=10273 user=0: from pid 30567
09-26 16:12:30.812  1451  2766 I ActivityManager: Killing 30011:com.medlife.customer/u0a273 (adj 0): stop com.medlife.customer
09-26 16:12:30.818  1451  2766 W ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{4610f1b u0 com.medlife.customer/.MainActivity t24974}: app died, no saved state
09-26 16:12:30.926  1451  1714 D AR_ADV_APPS_USAGE_COL: com.medlife.customer -> resizable apps -> USAGE 38817
09-26 16:12:31.912  1451  4565 I ActivityManager: Force stopping com.medlife.customer appid=10273 user=0: from pid 30594
09-26 16:13:41.434  3974 31010 D PowerCalculator: topApCounter com.medlife.customer
09-26 16:13:41.434  3974 31010 D PowerCalculator: topApCounter com.medlife.customer
09-26 16:13:41.434  3974 31010 D PowerCalculator: topApCounter com.medlife.customer
```

ADB logs post after disabling:

```
09-30 12:43:17.696  1992  3969 I ActivityManager: Force stopping com.medlife.customer appid=10102 user=0: from pid 5797
09-30 12:43:17.697  1992  3969 I ActivityManager: Killing 5609:com.medlife.customer/u0a102 (adj 0): stop com.medlife.customer
09-30 12:43:17.709  1992  3969 W ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{8440c12 u0 com.medlife.customer/.MainActivity t113}: app died, no saved state
09-30 12:43:18.010  1992  3969 I ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.medlife.customer/.MainActivity} from uid 2000
09-30 12:43:18.174  1992  2012 I ActivityManager: Start proc 5800:com.medlife.customer/u0a102 for activity com.medlife.customer/.MainActivity
09-30 12:43:18.505  5800  5819 I FA      :   adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.medlife.customer
09-30 12:43:18.975  5800  5879 I edlife.custome: Thread[44,tid=5879,Native,Thread*=0x75721b54ec00,peer=0x12fd1880,"create_react_context"] recursive attempt to load library "/data/app/com.medlife.customer-3_0cUdZvnpi5RWm0mKBAwA==/lib/x86_64/libfb.so"
09-30 12:43:19.225  5800  5891 D         : Successfully queried cache dir: /data/user_de/0/com.medlife.customer/code_cache
09-30 12:43:19.226  5800  5891 D RenderScript: Setting cache dir: /data/user_de/0/com.medlife.customer/code_cache
09-30 12:43:19.433  1928  1928 D SurfaceFlinger: duplicate layer name: changing com.medlife.customer/com.medlife.customer.MainActivity to com.medlife.customer/com.medlife.customer.MainActivity#1
09-30 12:43:19.614  5800  5883 I edlife.custome: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.medlife.customer-3_0cUdZvnpi5RWm0mKBAwA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.medlife.customer-3_0cUdZvnpi5RWm0mKBAwA==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/com.medlife.customer-3_0cUdZvnpi5RWm0mKBAwA==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64]]
09-30 12:43:19.616  5800  5883 I edlife.custome: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/org.apache.http.legacy.boot.jar", zip file "/data/app/com.medlife.customer-3_0cUdZvnpi5RWm0mKBAwA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.medlife.customer-3_0cUdZvnpi5RWm0mKBAwA==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/com.medlife.customer-3_0cUdZvnpi5RWm0mKBAwA==/base.apk!/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64]]
09-30 12:43:19.694  1992  2018 I ActivityManager: Displayed com.medlife.customer/.MainActivity: +1s549ms
09-30 12:43:21.337  1928  2346 W SurfaceFlinger: Attempting to set client state on removed layer: com.medlife.customer/com.medlife.customer.MainActivity#1
09-30 12:43:21.337  1928  2346 W SurfaceFlinger: Attempting to destroy on removed layer: com.medlife.customer/com.medlife.customer.MainActivity#1
09-30 12:43:23.086  5800  5952 E cr_VariationsUtils: Failed reading seed file "/data/user/0/com.medlife.customer/app_webview/variations_seed": /data/user/0/com.medlife.customer/app_webview/variations_seed (No such file or directory)
09-30 12:43:34.090  2128  2128 I LatinIme: onActivate() : EditorInfo = Package = com.medlife.customer : Type = Text : Learning = Disable : Suggestion = Hide : AutoCorrection = Disable : Microphone = Show : Incognito = Disable
09-30 12:43:34.395  2128  2128 W Conv2QueryExtension: Conv2Query not enabled due to current app [com.medlife.customer] not in whitelist
09-30 12:43:37.846  2128  2128 I LatinIme: onActivate() : EditorInfo = Package = com.medlife.customer : Type = Text : Learning = Disable : Suggestion = Hide : AutoCorrection = Disable : Microphone = Show : Incognito = Disable
09-30 12:43:37.856  2128  2128 W Conv2QueryExtension: Conv2Query not enabled due to current app [com.medlife.customer] not in whitelist
09-30 12:43:38.429  2128  2128 I LatinIme: onActivate() : EditorInfo = Package = com.medlife.customer : Type = Text : Learning = Disable : Suggestion = Hide : AutoCorrection = Disable : Microphone = Show : Incognito = Disable
09-30 12:43:38.465  2128  2128 W Conv2QueryExtension: Conv2Query not enabled due to current app [com.medlife.customer] not in whitelist
09-30 12:46:28.724  1992  2665 I ActivityManager: Force stopping com.medlife.customer appid=10102 user=0: from pid 6074
09-30 12:46:28.724  1992  2665 I ActivityManager: Killing 5800:com.medlife.customer/u0a102 (adj 0): stop com.medlife.customer
09-30 12:46:28.725  1992  2665 W ActivityManager: Force removing ActivityRecord{f56adcb u0 com.medlife.customer/.MainActivity t114}: app died, no saved state
09-30 12:46:29.671  1992  2666 I ActivityManager: Force stopping com.medlife.customer appid=10102 user=0: from pid 6091
```

Comment: Are you using a company restricted device with Miradora system or any similar system to it?

Comment: Hi, no via automation i am using android emulator and for manual testing i am using my own device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase the RAM and internal storage size that you are assigning to the emulator in order for that exception to go away. You are trying to do some action in the android code that's eating up the emulator's RAM and internal memory.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response. The issue is happening with real device as well which has plenty of storage available. Also the issue happens only when execution done via appium. If i stop the appium server mid execution the flickering stops, same way if i unplug my real device during execution on the error page, the flickering stops.

Comment: Anyways i tried by increasing the RAM and storage of emulator, but the issue atill exists

Comment: @ShivPratapSingh What is your version of appium and android device info too, please?

Comment: Hi @sharaf  appium version: 1.14.2  Android emulator>  Android version: 9

Comment: @ShivPratapSingh That issue is happening because the app is trying to cache a huge amount of data more than 6 MB in the device's RAM. Can you show the adb logs when executing on your android device not on emulator?

Comment: Hi @Sharaf, Have edited the question and added adb logs from real devices.Kinly have a look!

Comment: That's why the application is crashing when in debug mode and works fine in normal mode. The app is sending more than 5 log records per second and being marked as chatty so the android system triggered the DOS attack counter and terminated the app. You can send it as a bug for developers and they shall take care of it.
Refer to this link if you want to read more into that:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37054581

Comment: Hi @sharaf, Disabled all the logs and rebuild the apk. But still the same issue occurs.

Comment: @ShivPratapSingh share the logs after removing those logs and make sure the app is not marked as chatty in the logs anymore, please.

Comment: hi @sharaf, have added the logs post removing logs. Please have a look!

Comment: @ShivPratapSingh Is this crash happening while trying to open a webview inside the app?

Comment: No. Not opening webview. @sharaf